# Show wishlist only for logged in users

Tags: wishlist

How i can disable the wishlist in magento only for guest users and show to logged in users?

which files I need to change?

Many thanks

**[update]**
i have a file in /app/design/frontend/base/default/mytheme/layout/customer.xml with this code: `

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position>
        <liParams/><aParams>class="flat_top_icon icon-login-1"</aParams><!-- aggiungo classe -->
        </action>
    </reference>
    <remove name="reorder"></remove>
</customer_logged_out>`
```

Added the code inside, but not work:

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <!---<reference name="right">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_mini_login" before="-" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"/>
    </reference>-->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <reference name="top.links">
            <remove name="wishlist_link"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <remove name="wishlist_sidebar"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="wishlist_sidebar"/>
        </reference>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position>
        <liParams/><aParams>class="flat_top_icon icon-login-1"</aParams><!-- aggiungo classe -->
        </action>
    </reference>
    <remove name="reorder"></remove>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Answer (score 4):

Magento wishlist functionality works when coustomer logged in. But you can remove wishlist blocks for not logged in users. Add local.xml to your theme layout `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <remove name="wishlist_link"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <remove name="wishlist_sidebar"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="wishlist_sidebar"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_out>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply! but not work. i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is create an observer for events customer_login and customer_logout in your custom module and based on these events you can enable or disable wishlist module's output using below code

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/config')->->saveConfig('advanced/modules_disable_output/wishlist', <0 or 1>);
```